# How to load data from database to combo box (autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

Sometimes things which are so simple to understand and realize in jQuery can take ages to do them in ExtJS, although ExtJS is indeed a great library. What I am trying to do is to create a combo box with an autocomplete functionality.

Using a local store is quite straightforward.

First I created the store:

```
var searchOptions = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [{
        "name": "Value1"
    }, {
        "name": "Value2"
    }]
});
```

Then I created the combo box as such:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    displayField: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Insert NodeId',
    labelAlign: 'right',
    width: 200,
    margin: 5,
    id: 'nodeId',
    valueField: 'id',
    store: searchOptions,
    queryMode: 'local',
    minChars: 1,
    hideTrigger: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.store.load();
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I want to is to run this remote instead of local. If I understand correctly I need to send an Ajax request, get the data from my postgresql db and then what??? Where do I store the data? Is it possible to put them in a store and if yes, how do I define the form of the store?

Any help or example would be mostly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: they have all kinds of examples and a great documentation. You should be looking into the data package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching in internet and with the help of this [post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?57029-comboBox-getting-data-from-MySQL-database) I managed to make it work.

This is what I did:

First I created a store like:

```
var autoCompleteStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields:['onomasia'],
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: 'autocomplete/getautocomplete.php',
            method: 'POST'
        }),
    baseParams:{task: "onomasia"}      
});
```

Then I created a combo box:

```
// DEFINE THE COMBO BOX FOR THE AUTOCOMPLETE
var nodeOikismoiField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id:'nodeId',
    name: 'oikismos',
    fieldLabel: 'Insert NodeId',
    displayField: 'onomasia',
    store: autoCompleteStore,
    mode: 'remote',
    allowBlank: false,
    valueField: 'onomasia',
    anchor:'95%',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    labelAlign : 'right',
    width: 200,
    margin: 5,
    minChars:1
});
```

And I called the combo box inside my viewport.

Lastly my `getautocomplete.php` file looks like this:

```php
<?php
    include 'postgresConnect.php';

    $query = "SELECT onomasia FROM oikismoi_covered LIMIT 3"; 
    $resultImg = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
    $json = array();

    while ($oikismos = pg_fetch_row($resultImg)) {
        $json[] = array(
            'onomasia'=> $oikismos[0]
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is configure the `searchOptions` store with a proxy that can load the remote data. It should have a URL that points to a service for loading the data. Something like

```
 proxy : {
    type    : 'rest',
    url     : '/api/service/users',
    reader  : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'users'
    }
}
```

If you configure that service to filter it's values based on a query parameter named `query` then you can link the Combo Box to autocomplete. The request should look something like `http://domain.com/api/service/users?query=Frank`.

After setting the combobox queryMode to `'remote'` (or removing it since remote is the default), whatever value is input should be sent to the store proxy url with the value in the query parameter.